# Access VBA SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

The code below is a `SELECT` query and to pass the respective values to appropriate control boxes in MS Access. It is passing all the values except the value that it originally received from a listbox (`POA_Assigned_to_individual_Name.RowSource`).

It seems the SQL query is bringing `null` value as a result and unable to pass it to the listbox back.

```vb
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Incident_Record" & _
  " WHERE [Incident_Record].[SMART_Incident_Ticket] =  " & Me.Mod_SMART_Incident_Ticket.Value & " "

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
Totcount = rs.RecordCount

    If totcount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Match Found", vbCritical, "SMART Case"
        Call Clear_Modification_Fields
        Exit Sub
    End If

With Rs
    Do While Not Rs.EOF
    Mod_Remedy_Incident_Ticket = ![Remedy_Incident_Ticket]
    Mod_ECD_Portal_Incident_Ticket = ![ECD_Portal_Incident_Ticket]
    Mod_SMART_Problem_Ticket = ![SMART_Problem_Ticket]
    Mod_Issue_Summary = ![Issue_Summary]
    Mod_POA_Assigned_to_individual_Name = ![POA_Assigned_to_individual_Name]

    RS.MoveNext
    Loop
End with
```

The below code is to pass the value to the listbox, *POA_Assigned_to_individual_Name*.

```vb
Mod_POA_Assigned_to_individual_Name = ![POA_Assigned_to_individual_Name]
```

But `![POA_Assigned_to_individual_Name]` shows `null`.

Other than this all other fields are getting the values.

Comment: Is there a value associated with the `POA_Assigned_to_individual_Name` field when evaluating the SQL query 'manually' within the MS Access Query Designer, using a fixed value in place of `Me.Mod_SMART_Incident_Ticket.Value`? (or alternatively, leaving your form open and changing the criteria to `[Forms]![YourFormName]!Mod_SMART_Incident_Ticket`)

Comment: Lee, it seems you are trying to see if it is taking the value when I enter it in the form. Yes, that part of it works fine. But the issue is when I do a search for it after the fact. I am able to send the ListField value to the table. But when trying to retrieve the data, I am having the issue. I tried to see manually, and I don't see it is bringing any values.

Comment: No - I'm trying to see if the SQL query is returning any results when excluding the VBA code you are using to populate the form (hence why I suggest you could even use a fixed value in place of your criteria when testing). If the SQL query isn't returning values for this field when running it 'manually', then the issue is with the SQL statement itself or simply that your database does not contain any data for this particular field.

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing with recordset loop as those variables are overwrittern with each loop. What are *Mod* variables used for?

Comment: Lee, as per to you suggestion I just tried the SQL and it is only bringing a NULL value. Any reason, why it would not pick up the value, just for that.

Comment: Parfait, Though it is in a loop there will be only 1 record that the database can find.

Comment: @user3323922, have you verified that the field holds a value for the given criteria?

Comment: Yes, the field can hold the value. I am not sure why the sql brings a NULL value

Comment: You state "the field **can** hold the value"; the question is rather, do the records in your database **already** have a value associated with this field for the given criteria?

Comment: Why are you concatenating a space to the end of parameter in the SQL? Is [SMART_Incident_Ticket] a number or text type field?

Comment: Lee, yes my table already has a value for the associated field.

Comment: I have just removed the extra space on the sql query, but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Mod_POA_Assigned_to_individual_Name.RowSource = Nz(![POA_Assigned_to_individual_Name])
```

This fixed the issue
Thank you all for your effort.